# Global Window Side Input Halting Fixed Window Stage In Dataflow Streaming Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm working with a Dataflow streaming pipeline, and I've encountered an issue where using a side input in the global window locks up my main branch that uses Fixed windows of 30 seconds.  All the stages before "Zone Processing," where the side input is first provided, run smoothly. Once we hit the stage using the side input, it halts or dramatically slows down.

**Expected Behavior:**
My Zone Processing stage should be run immediately after the previous stage is completed.

**Actual Behavior:**
The stage waits a period of time before outputting, even though no time-consuming processing is done.
Looking at the dataflow input/output collection graphs for the stage "Zone Processing," we see that the output is typically processed almost 1 minute after the input was provided.  I can also see this in the stage logs.

The side input is fetched as expected every 30 seconds and is only 1-2kb.

Regarding the input data, I've tried sending both on-time and late data, and both had the same problem. This is still in early testing, so the input volume is very low. I only send a few pub-sub messages at a time via Postman.

**Pipeline Configuration:**

- Runner: Dataflow Runner v2
- SDK Version: Apache Beam Python 3.10 SDK 2.52.0
- Instance: n1-standard-2
- Dataflow Prime: Disabled

Here's a simplified version of my pipeline code.

```
class AddTimestampToMessage(DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        timestamp_str = element['timestamp']
        dt = datetime.fromisoformat(timestamp_str.rstrip('Z')).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
        unix_timestamp = dt.timestamp()
        yield TimestampedValue(element, unix_timestamp)


class FetchSideInputDataFromFirebase(DoFn):
    def __init__(self, databaseUrl, eventId):

        self.databaseUrl = databaseUrl
        self.eventId = eventId

    def start_bundle(self):
        """
        Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
        """
        # Initialization code for Firebase
        if not firebase_admin._apps:
    
            firebase_admin.initialize_app(None, options={
                'databaseURL': self.databaseUrl
            })

    def process(self, element):
        if (not self.eventId):
            logging.error('No event id provided to fetch side input data. Skipping...')
            return
        ref = db.reference('/events/' + self.eventId + '/side_input_data')
        data = ref.get()
        for key, value in data.items():
            yield (key, value)

class ProcessMessage(DoFn):
    def process(self, messageGroup, side_input=None, window=DoFn.WindowParam, timestamp=DoFn.TimestampParam):

        # * Takes the message group and outputs 3 records, using side input data
        record1 = {}
        record2 = {}
        record3 = {}

        for record in [record1, record2, record3]:
            yield record


def run(input_subscription, output_path, window_size=30.0, pipeline_args=None, project=None):
    
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True
    )

    with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:

        sideInputPColl = (
            pipeline
            | 'Periodic Impulse' >> PeriodicImpulse(fire_interval=window_size, apply_windowing=False)
            | 'Fetch Firebase Data' >> ParDo(FetchSideInputDataFromFirebase(...))
            | "Global Window" >> WindowInto(
                GlobalWindows(),
                trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(1)),
                accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
            )
        )

        (
            pipeline
            | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)
            | 'Add timestamp based on message event time' >> ParDo(AddTimestampToMessage())
            | "Window into Fixed Windows" >> WindowInto(
                  FixedWindows(window_size),
                  accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING,
                  allowed_lateness=432000 # allow 5 days of late data
            )
            | "Key by tag_id" >> WithKeys(lambda message: message['tag_id'])
            | "Group by tag_id" >> GroupByKey()
            # ------ here is where my issue is ------
            | "Zone Processing" >> ParDo(ProcessMessage(), pvalue.AsDict(sideInputPColl))
            | "Write to Bigquery" >> io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    'my_table',
                    create_disposition=io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                    write_disposition=io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
                    )
        )
```

**Things I have tried:**

- Tweaking side input settings

  - `AsSingleton` and `AsDict` options

```
side_input_update = pvalue.AsSingleton(sideInputPColl)
```

- Applied windowing to periodic impulse instead of global windows

  - I saw similar issues with this.

```
            side_input_update = (
                pipeline
                | 'Periodic Impulse' >> PeriodicImpulse(fire_interval=window_size, apply_windowing=True)
                | 'Fetch Firebase Data' >> ParDo(FetchSideInputDataFromFirebase(...))
            )
```

- Tried various global window triggering delays

  - This made no noticable difference

```
"Global Window" >> WindowInto(
                GlobalWindows(),
                trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(5)), # 1, 5, 30
                accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
            )
```

- Debugging using DirectRunner

  - The code works correctly in the direct runner. However, I am using a workaround for a bug with PeriodicImpulse so it only "pulses" when it first runs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with Side input global windows https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/28776 which may or may not be related to your problem. But looking at it, it looks similar to the above mentioned issue.

I would try the workaround of providing is by setting `num_workers` pipeline option to be greater than 1.

how many workers does your dataflow pipeline scale to?

Comment: note: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer].